# How to change data in local notification with a callback function in Ionic 3?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic3

I have looked far and wide but I can't seem to find any example of a callback function in Ionic 3 with the local notification plugin. The notification is working fine but I'm trying to make it change data after every notification. This way the notification next week will have new content.

I can fetch the new data but I can't seem to change the notification that has already been scheduled.

```
Ionic version: 3.1.1
Node version: 6.10.0
```

My notification-page.ts looks like this:

```
// This is where the data loads from the service.
// It happens when the view loads for the first time.
ionViewDidLoad() {

    // Get the JSON data from our itemApi
    this.itemApi.getItems().then(data => {

        this.items = data;

        let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.items.length)

        // Select the random object an pass it to the oneItem object
        this.oneItem = this.items[randomNumber];

    });

}



testNotification() {

        // The notification
        let notification = {
            id:1,
            title: this.oneItem.word,
            text: this.oneItem.description,
            every: "minute"
        };

        this.notifications.push(notification);

        if(this.platform.is('cordova')){

                // Cancel any existing notifications
                this.localNotifications.cancelAll().then(() => {

                    // Schedule the new notifications
                    this.localNotifications.schedule(this.notifications);

                    this.notifications = [];

                    let alert = this.alertController.create({
                        title: 'Notifications set',
                        buttons: ['Ok']
                    });

                    // Initializes the alert
                    alert.present();

                    // Creates a callback function on the schedule trigger - populates the notification with new data
                    this.localNotifications.on("schedule", function(){

                            // Get the JSON data from our itemApi
                            this.itemApi.getItems().then(data => {

                                this.items = data;

                                let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.items.length)

                                // Select the random object an pass it to the oneItem object
                                this.oneItem = this.items[randomNumber];

                            });

                            // The notification is created again in the callback
                            let notification = {
                                id:1,
                                title: this.oneItem.word,
                                text: this.oneItem.description,
                                every: "minute"
                            };

                            this.notifications.push(notification);

                    });
                    // Ends the callback function

                });

            }

}
// End of notification
```

I'm currenly trying to use the on("schedule") callback I found in the documentation. However, I can't seem to get it to work.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: there's a update method, check the plugin wiki on the github. Can't post an answer now, but here's the github https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/wiki/05.-Update and if you want to change AFTER it's presented you'll need to use .on('click') callback or .on('trigger').

Comment: I found the update method but I still can't get it to work. I have even tried to change the callback to the trigger. It still keeps sending the same notification.